# Github Integration with Azure Databricks

Tags: github, azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I followed the steps detailed in the official documentation (https://docs.databricks.com/repos/repos-setup.html).

However when I try to make a repo in Databricks - or checkout code from the Repo via a Databricks workflow I get the following error;

```
Failed to checkout Git repository: GIT_REMOTE_ERROR: Couldn't connect to server, reason: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

I don't think I will have access to correct this at my end.

My vague understanding is that I need to create certificates for the Github Repository and another one for the Databricks Cluster. Does anyone have any experience / links for how this can be done?

I am using github enterprise

Comment: Are you using GitHub or GitHub Enterprise?

Comment: Github enterprise